# Elasticsearch profile api in python library

Tags: python, elasticsearch, profiler

Elasticsearch has a very useful feature called profile API. That is you can get very useful information on the queries performed. I am using the python elasticsearch library to perform the queries and want to be able to get those information back but I don't see anywhere in the docs that this is possible. Have you managed to do it someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `profile="true"` to the body did the trick. In my opinion this should be an argument like size etc in the search method of the Elasticsearch class